# Open "localhost:8000" in edge with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch-file basically looking like this to open a webpage I'm hosting locally.

> @echo off
> start msedge "localhost:8000"
> pause

For some reason, it refuses to input the URL when opening. Doing just "localhost" or "google.com" works just fine. It is the colon or port that messes it up.

What is wrong?

Comment: I'm almost certain I know what's wrong, but just in case I don't, can you please check to see if `start "" msedge "localhost:8000"` works?

Answer (score 1):

If you use http://localhost:8000 it works, sometimes browsers "autofill" does not work correctly when you provide ports, better to provide full URL (with http://) on this cases.

Comment: Thank you. This worked without a hitch. :)